# A tool to format a long minified JavaScript code (jCarousel)

Tags: javascript, ide, formatting, jcarousel

I'd like to format JavaScript code of jCarousel to see what it does (to be able to debug it, and solve my problem). Visual Studio doesn't format it. Do you know any tool (free if you wish) to format long JS files?

**This is how jCarousel minified code looks like:**

[image]

---

**this is what a formatted JS file:**

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... even too much whitespace for being a minified js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code is available.. reading the [project website](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) sometimes helps.

https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel

Besides that, the unminified version is even included in the download archive...